# Limitations of Swing

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, event-dispatch-thread

We all know that since Swing is not thread-safe, it can only be executed in one thread at a time, called the EDT.

What should I use in order to have a swinglike inteface and components that allows visual multihreading (in other words, swing not limited to execute only in EDT)?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the limitations. These aren't the limitations of just Swing but pretty much any GUI library. Bottom line: You need to use background threads with all GUI libraries. I challenge you to show me one that doesn't have this same issue.

Comment: But programs have been made that have more than several "visual" actions occuring at the same time... This must be possible with GUIs somehow... Even if not thread safe, why couldn't programmers be allowed to be able to make a thread safe program by using the library properly?

Comment: The visual actions are driven by code that occurs on a background thread and then updates the GUI in a thread-safe way. And programmers *are* able to make a thread safe program by respecting thread safety. I think that this is a non-issue.

Comment: But why can't I then have one thread populating my JPanel with other JPanels while the other one is playing the animations on JProgressBar at the exact same time?
That is thread-safe...

Comment: Again, you need to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Until we can see, run, and understand your code, we're just blowing air talking about theoretical BS.

Comment: That was just an example... From what I know, it's impossible to make two separate visual changes to the GUI, since it all has to run on the same thread, the EDT? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Again, til we see an example, we can discuss til we're blue in the face. It should take hardly any time to build most GUI components, unless you have something unusual going on, and if you do, that unusual goings on should be done in a background thread.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 "why can't I have one thread populating ... while the other one ..." In Swing, a perfectly valid answer is "it doesn't work that way".  As already commented, UI systems in general don't work that way.  I suspect it's to make it easier (or 'feasible') to keep the UI self-consistent and updated properly, and also to make it easier to USE the library.  Theoretically you could make it another way, but if it is so buggy or so hard to use that you wouldn't want to use it, then you wouldn't want to use it.  If you really dislike it that much, write your own.

Comment: -1 and voting to close: the question not answerable without a _concrete_ problem (which isn't possible to post because there is none ;-).

Answer (score 4):

Use Swing.  You don't need your *application* executing in one thread, just changes to the GUI.

It's quite common to have multiple threads executing, and have each of them do things like:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        someFrame.setVisible(true);
        myCustomTableModel.updateWithNewData(newListOfData);
    }
});
```

Comment: But will I be able to access and change the same swing components (objects) from different threads at the same time? And I'm talking about multiple EDTs executing simultaneously...

Comment: Yes, you can safely call EventQueue.invokeLater from as many threads as you wish, without worrying about concurrency.  The system will never have multiple event dispatch threads, but you can create as many application threads as you want;  EventQueue.invokeLater properly handles merging your Runnable arguments into the execution of the event dispatch thread.